# How to auto refresh when user change postcode

Tags: functions, woocommerce-offtopic, wp-admin

I setup the shipping zones so if the customer is in the local area and enter the correct postcode, "Free local delivery" become active and replace other zones.

The problem is the customers is not aware that nothing is change unless they refresh the browser manually. My question is how can I add ajax auto-refresh automatically when customer change the post code?